# Game Theory : Eliminating weakly dominated strategies

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I have a question in game theory. Let's suppose we have two players A and B, let's say that A is a Girl, and B is a Boy. Both of them are in the same class.

Let's suppose that anyone of them can choose from two strategies : to love or like the other player(L), or reject (or not like : O).

- If both players like each others, then each of them will get 4 points : 2 points for being "loved", and 2 points for starting a relationship.
- If one player likes and the other rejects, the one who is "loved" will get 2 points, and the one who is rejected will lose 2 points : -2, for having his heart broken.
- If both players reject (none likes the other), then nothing changes : 0 points.

Question : What is the best response for, say : Player B ? How to eliminate weakly dominated strategies in this game?

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no dominated strategy because there is no strategy that has less utility across all the other player's strategies. For example, for player B, $U_B (L) = (4,-2)$ is not better or worse than $U_B (O) = (2,0)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just started learning Game Theory, and I wondered what would be the best response in this kind of games, where there is no better strategy to choose. +1

Comment: There isn't one best play, but there are several frameworks that prescribe (potentially) different strategies. The most famous of these would be the Nash mixed strategy equilibrium.

Comment: The usual way to answer questions like this is to look for Nash equilibria, which in this case are $(L,L)$ and $(O,O)$. In a simple game like this, where you can present the payoffs in a 2D table you find those by looking at such cells, that the $A$ player cannot improve his payoff by switching to another strategy ($B$ still playing the same), and $B$ cannot improve by switching ($A$ playing the same). You can see how e.g. at $(L,L)$ by switching his strategy $A$ would lose $2$, and so would $B$.

Comment: @dbx  thank you so much, I see ... thanks for the reference, I will look into nash mixed strategy equilibrium. Best

Comment: @yassem , Yes, You are right, this game has 2 Nash equilibria, there is no way to look for dominant strategies as the game is symmetric (same options for A and B). Thanks : Best !